# How to calculate sum of group in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find how to calculate a new SQL column that works on a formula involving 'NA' values. I think that I am not getting my desired result because of either the 'NA' values or because of my grouping. Please see the table and formula below:

My table is the following:

```
website session score
 google    1       1
 google    2       NA
 bbc       3       2
 bbc       4       4
 bbc       5       5
```

The formula i am using to created a new calculated field is the following:

```
select
    website,
    (sum(score IN (4,5))/sum((score is not null)) - sum(score IN (1,2))/sum(score is not null))*100 as new_column
from 
    my_table
group by 
    website
```

Essentially the formula is trying to do the following:

Sum up those values in the score column that are either 4 or 5, then divide them by the sum of the numbers in the score column that do exist.

Then deduct the following:

Sum up those values in the score column that are either 1 or 2, then divide them by the sum of the numbers in the score column that do exist.

Finally:

Multiply the entire output by 100

**The formula has to be applied to each group.**

So you should have the following desired result:

Taking only the first group of "google"

You have 4 not null values. you have 2 values whereby the value is IN (1,2) and 0 values in (4,5).

so you would have the following formula:

((0/4)-(2/4))*100

-2/4 * 100

= -50

however, when calculating this in SQL i recieve the value -100. which does not make sense to me. can anyone help?

Comment: you could "select" each of your operations to check where is the error, but I bet the issue is that you are grouping by website, and google only have 2 rows, not 4, and one of the selected rows is null, so it is not counted...

Comment: The query looks fine to me. BTW: I suppose this is MySQL or MariaDB? Then please add that tag. SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: SQLITE and have added tag

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras how can i count the null row?

Comment: @BeansOnToast In your example you stated there are 2 values whereby the value is IN(1,2) for 'google'. However on your table there is only 1 record with score value IN(1,2). Second record is NA or null for google.

Comment: You coud try select website, sum(score IN (4,5))/sum((score) as NumberOne, sum(score IN (1,2))/sum(score) as numberTwo 
(sum(score IN (4,5))/sum((score)) - sum(score IN (1,2))/sum(score))*100 as new_column from  my_table group by website

Comment: The formula lacks any mentioning of groups. You group by website. Are "sum of values 4 and 5" and "sum of values 1 and 2" meant per group? (I guess yes.) Is "sum of numbers" also meant per group or for the whole table? (I don't know.)

Comment: On a side note: `sum(score is not null)` is usually written as `count(score)`. But as has been mentioned by NeutralHandle: "the sum of the numbers in the score column" would instead be `sum(score)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one not null values for Google. The sum of it is one. So your formula is resulting in (0-1/1)*100 which is -100, which is what it is giving.

What I think you want is the count of all Google records divided by the count of all non-null records?

Comment: so the formula is correct then? I mean if it gave -100 it would be correct!

Comment: Yes the formula does what you described as I understood it. Your manual example does something else.

Comment: ah okay - what would be the expected result for the second group BBC?

Comment: (2/3 - 1/3) * 100 = 100/3 = 33.333

Comment: yep - got the same answer so the formula is correct! thanks for the help!

Comment: Divided by sum not count so it's (9/11-2/11)*100, which is 700/11

Comment: @NeutralHandle: Ah, yes, I got confused. You are right.

Comment: I don't know... do you really get your desired result with the first website?

Comment: I'm not actually sure anymore what the desired result is - I expect a value between 100 and -100

Answer (score 1):

I advise multiplying by 1.0 each sum so that it doesn't round the sum to int value which would result in zero(0) for 'bbc' group.

Here is the updated version of your query(Check also SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5fca1/8):

```
select website,
    (sum(score IN (4,5)) * 1.0/sum(score is not null) - sum(score IN (1,2)) * 1.0/sum(score is not null))*100.0 as new_column
from my_table
group by website
```

Comment: While this does not answer the question, this is still good advice. I find it horrible that `/` does not mean "division", but "division or integer-division depending on the types" in some SQL dialects (including SQLite). I can't imagine how many program errors may originate from this "feature" :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a difference between percentage of (4,5) and (1,2) for each group. Since null values are ignored in aggregation, you could simply do

```
(avg(score in (4,5)) - avg(score in (1,2)))*100
```

Answer (score -1):

From your manual example, You may first sum all the not null values, and then use that value in your code -

```
WITH NN_SUM AS (SELECT SUM(score is not null) NOT_NULL_SUM
                FROM my_table)
SELECT website,
       (((sum(score IN (4,5)) - sum(score IN (1,2))) / NOT_NULL_SUM) * 100 as new_column
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN NN_SUM
GROUP BY website;
```